# How to get the field value that is excluded in order to change the row background

Tags: django, django-tables2

I want to display a table in which some fields are excluded, because I do not want to display them in a table.
At the same time, I want to change the color in the row based on the values ​​that are excluded. Is it possible to do this with django-table2 ?

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from web_logic.models import Stations
from django_tables2.utils import A


class StationTable(tables.Table):
    """

    """

    station_id = tables.LinkColumn()
    rack_sum = tables.LinkColumn("racks_page", args=[A('pk')], verbose_name='Кол-во стоек')
    status = tables.BooleanColumn()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StationTable, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_station_id(self, value):
        print(value)
        return "%s " % value

    class Meta:
        model = Stations
        exclude = (
            "id",
            "onboot_time",
            'certificat_key',
            'private_key',
            "status",
            "ipadress",
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
        )
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        attrs = {
            "class": "table",
            "td": {"class": "table-hover",},
            "thead": {"class": "table-dark"},
        }
```

For example, the status field describes a state for the entire row. It can be True or False. I do not want to display the column with this field, but I want to highlight (change the color of the line) based on the value for this field. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this using [`row_attrs`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/column-attributes.html#row-attributes):

```
class StationTable(tables.Table):
    station_id = tables.LinkColumn()
    rack_sum = tables.LinkColumn("racks_page", args=[A('pk')], verbose_name='Кол-во стоек')

    def render_station_id(self, value):
        return "%s " % value

    class Meta:
        model = Stations
        exclude = (
            "id",
            "onboot_time",
            'certificat_key',
            'private_key',
            "status",
            "ipadress",
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
        )
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
        attrs = {
            "class": "table",
            "td": {"class": "table-hover",},
            "thead": {"class": "table-dark"},
        }
        row_attrs = {
            "class": lambda record: "info" if record.status else ""
        }
```

This will add attribute `class="info"` to the `<tr>`-tag of rows with `status = True`.